# linker error compiling pcl_ros

Tags: pcl, ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-oneiric, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,
I downloaded and I've tried to compile pcl_ros, but  I got the following errors:

```
svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/
roscd pcl_ros
rosmake --rosdep-install
```

### /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/sensor_msgs/PointField.h:98:35: warning: unused parameter ‘seq’ [-Wunused-parameter]
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/pcl_viewer
CMakeFiles/pcl_viewer.dir/pcd_viewer.cpp.o: In function `pp_callback(pcl::visualization::PointPickingEvent const&, void*)': pcd_viewer.cpp:(.text+0x1d85): undefined reference to` pcl::visualization::PCLPlotter::addFeatureHistogram(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, int, int)'
pcd_viewer.cpp:(.text+0x21d0): undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLPlotter::spinOnce(int)' CMakeFiles/pcl_viewer.dir/pcd_viewer.cpp.o: In function` main':
pcd_viewer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2fc7): undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLPlotter::addFeatureHistogram(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int)' pcd_viewer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4fdd): undefined reference to` pcl::visualization::PCLPlotter::PCLPlotter(char const*)'
pcd_viewer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x59a9): undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLPlotter::spin()' CMakeFiles/pcl_viewer.dir/pcd_viewer.cpp.o: In function` _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z16isValidFieldNameRKSs':
pcd_viewer.cpp:(.text.startup+0x67d6): undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLPlotter::PCLPlotter(char const*)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[3]: *** [bin/pcl_viewer] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/aldo/Projects/4thRC/BergamoComponents/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
make[2]: *** [visualization/tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_viewer.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/aldo/Projects/4thRC/BergamoComponents/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/aldo/Projects/4thRC/BergamoComponents/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pcl written to:                                                          [ 1 Active 40/42 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/aldo/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120815-102529/pcl/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl [FAIL] [ 5726.81 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pcl.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 41 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory

any idea?
Note: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with ROS electric and libpcl_visualization.so stays in ./pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build/lib/
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41452/linker-error-compiling-pcl_ros/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

I have just compiled a recent version of PCL this way (untested, at your own risk!) by disabling some things. The things that I disabled may be needed by you, though.

Actually, my one built against revision 6849 of pcl, but what worked there might work here (yours is one of the problems that came up).

Note that this answer applies to Ubuntu 11.10.

Instructions:

- Start the build. When pcl build fails, go to `perception_pcl_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/visualization/tools/CMakeLists.txt` and comment out the lines regarding pcd_viewer (you will not get the pcd_viewer). This should stop the error that you are having, which is because it tries to build it even though the VTK version does not supply everything it needs.
- Also, you will probably need to disable some modules. You do this by going into `perception_pcl_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build`, running `ccmake ..` (you might have to install `cmake-gui-curses`) and disabling the modules. I disabled apps, modeller, tools, surface, and examples modules, but you may have better luck with different ones. I probably didn't need to disable them all.
- Depending on which modules you disable, you may have to remove them from the linker flags exported by `perception_pcl_unstable/pcl/manifest.xml` - for example, I removed `-lpcl_surface`

Hope this helps someone.

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2012-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1